# UIKit - How to sort a table?

Tags: html, uikit

I use UIKit table (https://getuikit.com/docs/table) in my project. I want to add ability to sort the table by columns' headers (arrows next to the header's name) and add pagination (below the table). In my HTML code I have

```html
<table class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-table-divider">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Table Heading</th>
                        <th>Table Heading</th>
                        <th>Table Heading</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table Data</td>
                        <td>Table Data</td>
                        <td>Table Data</td>
                        <span uk-icon="heart"></span>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table Data</td>
                        <td>Table Data</td>
                        <td>Table Data</td>
                        <span uk-icon="heart"></span>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table Data</td>
                        <td>Table Data</td>
                        <td>Table Data</td>
                        <span uk-icon="heart"></span>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

How do I add sorting and pagination to a table?

Answer (score 2):

Quite a bit late reply, but I am using it now.

An a example:

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>UIKit - Datatable example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- UIkit CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.13.7/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
    <!-- UIkit JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.13.7/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.13.7/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Datatables.net -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/dataTables.uikit.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#awesome-datatable').DataTable( {
                //~ dom: "<'bottom'flp><'clear'>i",
                serverSide: false,
                ordering: true,
                searching: true,
                //~ data:           data,
                deferRender:    true,
                scrollY:        400,
                scrollCollapse: false,
                scroller:       false,
                stateSave: false,
                paging:   true,
                info:     true,
                order: [[ 0, "desc" ]]
            } );
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center">
    <table id="awesome-datatable" class="uk-table uk-table-small uk-table-hover uk-table-striped">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 20%;">
        <col style="width: 40%;">
        <col style="width: 40%;">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Link</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Description</strong></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>UIKit</strong></td>
            <td><a href="https://getuikit.com/">https://getuikit.com/</a></td>
            <td>A lightweight and modular front-end framework for developing fast and powerful web interfaces. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Datatables - UIKit 3</strong></td>
            <td><a href="https://datatables.net/examples/styling/uikit.html">https://datatables.net/examples/styling/uikit.html</a></td>
            <td>Add advanced interaction controls to your HTML tables the free and easy way.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Stackoverflow</strong></td>
            <td><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">https://stackoverflow.com/</a></td>
            <td>Public questions and answers</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

DataTables is a powerful jquery plugin for add some essential functions to table like pagination, ordering etc.

- Customize DataTables adding the necessary functions: https://datatables.net/download (UIkit is in development: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/uikit)
- Download the files or use the CDN and add the code before the `</head>` closing tag
- This is a basic configuration: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.htm

Comment: DataTables can answer the question, but please add an example of how answer the question